# Arduino/C++ struct/class with variable compile-time constant

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to create a register map for an SPI-device-driver-class. Traditionally, this is done using (often hundreds of) `#define` statements, such as `#define DEVICE_REG_2C_REGISTER_NAME 0x2C`

I would prefer to avoid this method since I don't need those constants available outside of the driver-class. I would also like to encapsulate the constants within a struct inside the driver class, so I can access them using `device.registers.register`

Finally, I would like any bitmasks that are applicable to each register to be available to me in the compiler, and I would like all of this information to be compile-time constant, so as to not waste the very limited memory available to me on the ATmega328P.

A somewhat-elegant solution which I have found is to use a `RegisterList` struct, which contains a bunch of `Register` structs, each of which contains an `enum` which holds the information I want. Something like this:

```
class SPIDevive {
  struct RegisterList {
    struct Register {
      enum {
        Address = 0x2C,
        bitMask1 = 0x80,
        bitMask2 = 0x30,
      };
    } r2C_REGISTER_NAME;
    // more registers here
  } registers;
}
```

This works pretty well, BUT for the sake of code brevity, I was hoping to be able to pass the `Register` struct itself as an argument to various functions within the `driver` class that read and write to device registers, and have those functions call `register.address`, rather than actually passing `register.address` as an argument. To that end, I have attempted the following:

```
class SPIDevive {
  struct Register { constexpr byte address() { return 0; } };

  struct RegisterList {
    struct : Register {
      enum {
        Address = 0x2C,
        bitMask1 = 0x80,
        bitMask2 = 0x30,
      };
      constexpr byte address() { return Address; }
    } r2C_REGISTER_NAME;
    // more registers here
  } registers;


  byte Read(Register reg) {           // invoked using Read(registers.reg);
    SPI.read(reg.address());          // reg.address() is always zero
    // do stuff
  }

  byte Read(byte address) {           // alternative method, requires using Read(registers.reg.address);
    SPI.read(address);
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

The practical difference is minimal, but `Read(Register reg)` feels much safer than `Read(byte address)`. Unfortunately, the version of C++ supported by the Arduino compiler does not allow virtual consexpressions, so whenever I call `Read()`, `reg.Address()` always returns zero. Is there a way to tell the compiler that `Read()` needs to expect a `Register` object as an argument, which will have a property called `Address`, which will be a compile-time constant, but still let `Address` return a different value for each `Register` struct? Or must I always pass `registers.reg.Address` as my function arguments?

Comment: IMHO, you should create a base class that models the SPI register, each member is a SPI register.  One method is to create a pointer to the base class and assign it the starting physical address of the SPI register group.  Repeat for each SPI register group.  If you want to gamble, you could make an array of the SPI register structure and assign the address to the first SPI register group.

Comment: The problem with that is that I'd have to allocate heap memory for each class. My objective here is really just to create a register map that will work well with Intellisense, and then compile ONLY the ones I'm using directly into the program space like an enum or #define.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here.  Let's say I have a bank of SPI registers at address 0x10000.  I would take a pointer of type SPI register class and assign the pointer to point to 0x10000.  No heap space required.  The idea is model a bunch of registers to  hardware, then assign a pointer of the model type to point to the physical memory.  Some embedded systems compilers allow to you specify the address of a variable at declaration time.